# Move object in array from composition API with vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I would like to know how can I move an object in array from composition API with draggable (vuedraggable).

Currently I have this :

```
// State
const state = reactive({
    post: null,
});

export default function postStore() {

    // Mutations
    const MOVE_COMMENT = (payload) => {
        let comment = state.post.comments[payload.oldIndex]
        
        state.post.comments.splice(payload.oldIndex, 1)
        state.post.comments.splice(payload.newIndex, 0, comment)
    };

    // Actions
    const moveComment = (payload) => {
        MOVE_COMMENT(payload)
    };

    return {
        ...toRefs(state),
        moveComment
    }
}
```

And I call my function from my component :

```
import draggable from 'vuedraggable';

...

<draggable :list="post.comments" @end="onEndDraggable">
    <template #item="{element}">
        <div>{{element.title}}</div>
    </template>
</draggable>

...

setup() {
    let { post, moveComment } = postStore();

    let onEndDraggable = (data) => {
        moveComment({
            newIndex: data.newIndex,
            oldIndex: data.oldIndex
        })
    }

    return { onEndDraggable }
}
```

When I drag the first item on second position, the first item stay first item. But if I drag the first item on third position, the first item become second item..

Comment: Your code seems to [work correctly](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-shifting-array-elements): it moves the old item down, shifting intermediate items towards `oldIndex`. Why do you say it doesn't work?

Comment: Thank you @tony19 for your comment ! I updated my code and created a demo from your code https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-shifting-array-elements-wpdmq9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :modelValue instead of :list [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-shifting-array-elements-wpdmq9)

```
<draggable :modelValue="post.comments" item-key="title" @end="onEndDraggable">
    <template #item="{element}">
        <div>{{element.title}}</div>
    </template>
</draggable>
```